# Did black people commit 18 times more murders per capita than white people in 2021?

Tags: united-states, criminology, statistics, race

The picture below is posted on [4chan.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4chan) (a [NSFW website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work)) and seems to claim that in 2021, black people committed 18 times more murders per capita than White people?

[image: chart with pensive MLK Jr. meme with text: "WHEN YOU REALIZE YOUR PEOPLE WERE BEING JUDGED BY THE CONTENT OF THEIR CHARACTER ALL ALONG"]

| ages | white male Murderers per 100,000 | hispanic male Murderers per 100,000 | black male Murderers per 100,000 | black female Murderers per 100,000 | hispanic female Murderers per 100,000 | white female Murderers per 100,000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15-64 | 5.2 | 17.4 | 95.5 | 8.7 | 3.6 | 1.1 |
| 5-14 | 0.2 | 0.8 | 4.9 |  |  |  |
| 15-24 | 8.3 | 28.1 | 207.4 | 16.9 | 4.8 | 1.4 |
| 25-34 | 7.6 | 23.5 | 119.5 | 13.3 | 5.7 | 1.9 |
| 35-64 | 3.6 | 9.4 | 38.4 | 3.9 | 2.2 | 0.8 |
| 65+ | 0.6 | 1.2 | 3.8 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.1 |
| All | 3.5 | 11.9 | 64.4 | 5.8 | 2.4 | 0.7 |
| Projected Lifetime | 274 | 819 | 4508 | 423 | 174 | 59 |

Any truth to that?

I couldn't find raw data for 2021 myself, but found data for 2019 at [Arrests by Race and Ethnicity, 2019](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2019/crime-in-the-u.s.-2019/topic-pages/tables/table-43) (FBI.gov):

```
{
    "Offense charged": "Murder and nonnegligent manslaughter",
    "Total": "7,964",
    "White": "3,650",
    "Black or African American": "4,078",
    "American Indian or Alaska Native": "125",
    "Asian": "83",
    "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander": "28",
    "Total.1": 100.0,
    "White.1": 45.8,
    "Black or African American.1": 51.2,
    "American Indian or Alaska Native.1": 1.6,
    "Asian.1": 1.0,
    "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander.1": 0.4,
    "Total2": "6,474",
    "Hispanic or Latino": "1,341",
    "Not Hispanic or Latino": "5,133",
    "Total.2": 100.0,
    "Hispanic or Latino.1": 20.7,
    "Not Hispanic or Latino.1": 79.3
}
```

and.. if there are 224,789,109 "white people" and 41,393,012 "Black or African American" people in USA at 2019 (see [Neilsberg Research](https://www.neilsberg.com/insights/united-states-population-by-race/) then..
(Edit: removed some very wrong math here, sorry about that)

```
blackMurders = 4078;
blackPopulation = 41393012;
whiteMurders = 3650;
whitePopulation = 224789109;
murderPerCapitaWhite = (whiteMurders / whitePopulation) * 100000; // 1.6237441467860438 
murderPerCapitaBlack = (blackMurders / blackPopulation) * 100000; // 9.851904471218475 

murderPerCapitaBlack / murderPerCapitaWhite; // 6.067399528872102
```

seemingly 6x in 2019? (entirely possible that I messed up the math, again, sorry)

Did black people commit 18 times more murders per capita than white people in 2021?

Comment: I do not get it, populations are roughly 5.5 times differ, while murders count is almost the same. Where does 18 came from?

Comment: Moreover, this numbers do not correlate with numbers in the colored table, which is indeed shows around 18.

Comment: @dEmigOd 64.4/3.5 = 18.4

Comment: That data is arrests not "murders committed". There may be other reasons one race is arrested at a higher rate. What is a "murder committed", if 5 people are charged with manslaughter of one person is that really 5 murders?

Comment: I think a similar question has been asked before, and was based on statistics with a very small data sample for the group alleged to be prolific murderers. Too small to be extrapolated.

Comment: In addition to differential arrests, wealthy people can afford lawyers who can plea-bargain or mount an effective defence, whereas poor people are likely to wind up with one overworked public defender. This affects charging behaviour by police; charge the indigent guy, but don't charge they guy with the expensive lawyer because it means more work. In the US black people in general are significantly poorer than white people. And of course, there is measurable racism in every stage of the US justice system from initial stop to final sentencing.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you are correct. Are you referring to this question and answer specifically? https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32694/are-black-americans-responsible-for-more-than-50-of-homicides?rq=1 I didn't notice anything about small sample sizes, but it does seem to address the issue of murders committed versus merely arrests. There is an accepted answer. Data was for 2013 and 2014. Seems like this is a duplicate question, no?

Comment: @EllieKesselman thanks for finding it (I did a search but missed it). It's not the one I had in mind, wherein someone alleged that the stats were deliberately misrepresented (by FBI or DOJ ??) IIR it involved black on black, white on black... perms etc offences. One of the stats had a very small sample size (less than 10?) but had been extrapolated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are black Americans responsible for more than 50% of homicides?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32694/are-black-americans-responsible-for-more-than-50-of-homicides)

Comment: @JeromeViveiros no, but it's a related question.

Comment: @EllieKesselman I don't think it's a duplicate, especially since OP says they are unable to find the 2021 data.

Comment: Note that even if the figures are correct (no idea if they are or not), there are a lot of correlating factors which could explain this a lot better than the “character” of people of a given skin color: income, education, where they live, which are all very strongly correlated.

Comment: @jcaron : no one claimed that skin color is the cause, that would be a strawman argument. Those who use these statistics in their arguments claim that it is the cultural values and social norms among black people which are the driving factor, and push for a change in attitude.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Even if wealth influences it, it cannot be by a factor of 18. To claim that 95% of white murderers are not charged because they are rich and can afford the best lawyers and they don't even get charged because it means more work, would be absurd. And "systematic racism" is not an excuse if the Asians were discriminated against just as strongly (or even more strongly) 80-100 years ago, but they have on average better income than whites. Given this, one might dare to think about personal choices, cultural values, social norms within a community, etc. to be an important factor.

Comment: @vsz I'm not saying it explains the whole difference, just that its one more factor.

Comment: @vsz A group of a people who were a major despised underclass for centuries to a group of people who, by and large, are immigrants since the 1960s seems largely incomparable.